# How can I find data in sheet using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have workbook with sheets named Contacts and Help. In Help sheet I have Button which shows inputbox and asks "What client you would like to find?"
When I input name like Samuel Smith. I would like that VBA would go to Contacts sheet and find me Samuel Smith and offset to one column right and copy the Firm where Samuel Smith works. Then paste it to Help sheet and find next Samuel Smith. I would love to do this even if there were 50 Samuel Smith's in Contacts! Just don't know how to do this so any help is much appreciated!

Thank you all for your answers in advance.

Comment: So user inputs "Samuel Smith" but you then want to find all Samuels ?

Comment: Do you need to use VBA? It sounds like you could use a formula instead, if you wanted.

Comment: @TimWilliams no mistyped that all Samuel Smiths.

Comment: @BruceWayne No need to use VBA if it's easier to do with formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on this hole night and now I know how to do this!

```
Option Explicit
'''''''
Dim Find_Inp As String
Dim Find As Variant
Dim Error_ As Integer
'''''''

Sub Test2()
On Error Resume Next

Sheet1.Select
Range("A8:G100").ClearContents

Find_Inp = InputBox("Please input Account!")
If Find_Inp = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

MsgBox "This will take some time please wait."
Sheet2.Select
Call Macro1 'Sort macro

Call Find_Full
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Function

```
Private Function Find_Full()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
'''''''
Dim Account_Column As Variant
Dim Result As Range, Result2 As Range
Dim LastAccount As Long
Dim NextAccount As Long
Dim Find_repeat As Integer
'''''''

Sheets("Contacts").Select
Account_Column = Range("G1").Select


Find = Cells.Find(What:=Find_Inp, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Find_repeat:

If Find = True Then
Set Result = ActiveCell

    LastAccount = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    NextAccount = LastAccount + 1

    Result.Copy 'Where the name
    Sheet1.Select
    Range("C" & NextAccount).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    Result.Offset(0, -2).Copy   'Where the firm name is
    Sheet1.Select
    Range("C" & NextAccount).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    Sheet2.Select
    Result.Offset(0, -1).Copy   'Where the email is
    Sheet1.Select
    Range("C" & NextAccount).Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    Sheet2.Select
    Result.Offset(0, 9).Copy    'Where the phone number
    Sheet1.Select
    Range("C" & NextAccount).Offset(0, -2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    Sheet2.Select
    Result.Offset(0, 10).Copy   'Where the work number is
    Sheet1.Select
    Range("C" & NextAccount).Offset(0, -1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    Sheet2.Select
    Result.Offset(0, 4).Copy    'Where the firm addres is
    Sheet1.Select
    Range("C" & NextAccount).Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    Sheet2.Select
    Result.Offset(0, 5).Copy    'Where the title is
    Sheet1.Select
    Range("C" & NextAccount).Offset(0, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    Error_ = 0

End If

Sheet2.Select
Result.Offset(1, 0).Select
Set Result2 = ActiveCell

If Result2 = Find_Inp Then
    GoTo Find_repeat
Else
    Sheet1.Select
    Range("A1").Select
End If

ErrorHandler:

If Error_ = 1 Then
    Sheet1.Select
    Range("A1").Select
    MsgBox "Account was not found! Try again."
End If

Error_ = 1

End Function
```

Sort Macro

```
 Private Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Contacts").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Contacts").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Contacts").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:AJ2106")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are my custom function, that can find and return the result in Array.

From the find result you should able to solve your problem.

Hope this help !

```
Sub test()
'The result will be on Column C, because offset = 1
Dim nItem, Found As Variant

Found = iFind("Concatenate", Columns(2), 1)

  For Each nItem In Found
      MsgBox nItem
  Next

End Sub


Function iFind(ByVal findText As String, ByVal nColumn As Range, ByVal offsetColumn As Single, _
                Optional ByVal startRow As Single = 1, Optional ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean = False) As Variant
'Return Array of Range
'nColumn - Column to find
'offsetColumn - offset column to return

Dim WBD As Workbook
Dim WSD As Worksheet
Dim lastRow, tCount, nCount, nRow, nCol, N As Single
Dim nColRng, dataRng As Range
Dim compare As VbCompareMethod
Dim nArray As Variant
ReDim nArray(0)

    Set WSD = nColumn.Parent

    'Ensure only on column selected to consider lastRow
    Set nColRng = nColumn.Columns(1)
    nCol = nColRng.Column

    'Get the lastRow
    On Error Resume Next
        lastRow = startRow
        lastRow = nColRng.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        If lastRow < startRow Then lastRow = startRow
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set dataRng = Intersect(WSD.Range(WSD.Rows(startRow), WSD.Rows(lastRow)), nColRng)

    tCount = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(dataRng, findText)
    If tCount > 0 Then
        nCount = 0
        N = 0
        Do While nCount < tCount
            nRow = Excel.Application.Match(findText, dataRng, 0) + dataRng(1).Row - 1
            If caseSensitive = True Then
                compare = vbBinaryCompare
            Else
                compare = vbTextCompare
            End If

            'Add into array, only if matching case
            If InStr(1, findText, WSD.Cells(nRow, nCol), compare) Then
                ReDim Preserve nArray(N)
                nArray(N) = WSD.Cells(nRow, nCol + offsetColumn)
                N = N + 1
            End If

            nCount = nCount + 1
            'Resize dataRng
            Set dataRng = Intersect(WSD.Range(WSD.Rows(nRow + 1), WSD.Rows(lastRow)), nColRng)
        Loop
    End If

    iFind = nArray
End Function
```